# Change NetBeans Debugger Command

Tags: c++, gdb, netbeans-6.9

I have a .gdbinit file to set the solib-absolute-prefix and solib-search-path when attaching a debugger from NetBeans. I've turned on the debugger console (by adding `-J-Dgdb.console.window=true` to `netbeans_default_options` in /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/etc/netbeans.conf) and it tells me:

```
Debugger Command: [/path/to/gdb, -nx, --nw, --silent, --interpreter=mi]
```

The -nx is preventing it from loading my .gdbinit file.

Is there any way in NetBeans to either (1) remove -nx from that command, (2) specify a .gdbinit file to load with gdb, or (3) specify library search paths explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, you can add `-J-Dgdb.init.enable=true`to `netbeans_default_options` in /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/etc/netbeans.conf and it will load the .gdbinit file.